# Integral for a particle in a central field

Tags: integration, classical-mechanics

I am attempting to solve an integral for the path of a particle in a central field given by
$$U=-\frac{\alpha}{r}+\frac{\beta}{r^2}$$
The integral in question is
$$\theta-\theta_0=L\int\frac{dr}{r^2\sqrt{2m(E+\frac{\alpha}{r}-\frac{\beta}{r^2}-\frac{L^2}{2mr^2})}}$$
**Attempt**

Making the substitution $r=\frac{1}{s-x}$, where $x$ is some constant to be determined we are left with
$$-L\int\frac{ds}{\sqrt{2mE+2m\alpha(s-x)-2m\beta(s-x)^2-L^2(s-x)^2}}$$
I then chose $x=-\frac{m\alpha}{L^2}$ so that the term linear in $s$ would drop out leaving
$$-L\int\frac{ds}{\sqrt{2mE+\frac{m^2\alpha^2}{L^2}-2m\beta s^2-4\frac{m^2\beta\alpha}{L^2}s-2\frac{m^3\alpha^2\beta}{L^4}-L^2s^2}}$$
I had in mind from here a conversion into the standard form for the $\arcsin$ however the $\beta$ terms will not allow this. I do not know how to proceed from here, if that is even possible.

Comment: Instead of doing the integral directly, try the following: *before* integrating, change variables, first to $s=1/r$. This should give something like $(ds/d\theta)^2=A+Bs+Cs^2$. Complete the square on the RHS then change variables again to $s-\text{const}=u$, yielding $(du/d\theta)=\sqrt{u^2+D}$, which is much more pleasant to integrate. Rather call this $\theta(r)$ the trajectory. A 'path integral' means something quite different. $A,B,C,D$ are constants depending on $m,L,E,\alpha,\beta$

Comment: If you're not attached to doing this integral, it's probably easier to use the [Binet equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation), since it reduces to $$u''(\phi) = \frac{\alpha m}{L^2} - \left(1 - 2 \frac{\beta m}{L^2} \right) u(\phi)$$in this case (where $u = r^{-1}$.)  This is a pretty easy ODE to solve.

Comment: I am simply interested in how to find the trajectory of a particle in an arbitrary central field. Would you recommend the Binet equation for all central fields of this form? I will need to read up on it before applying it.

Comment: The Binet equation gives you a second-order ODE for $u(\phi)$.  For an arbitrary potential, though, the ODE is not linear;  it's only linear (and easy to solve in closed form) for potentials of the form you wrote above.  You could still use numerical techniques to explore the solution space, though, or iterative perturbational techniques to get an approximate solution if the potential is "close" to the above form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the tip that Sal posted, I begin by changing variables before integration
$$\frac{d\theta}{dr}=\frac{L}{mr^2}\sqrt{\frac{m}{2(E-U_{eff})}}$$
Substituting $s=\frac{1}{r}$
$$\left(\frac{ds}{d\theta}\right)^2=-\frac{m}{L^2}\left(2E+2\alpha s-2\beta s^2-\frac{L^2}{m}s^2\right)$$
From here, I set $$A=-\frac{2mE}{L^2},\ \ \ B=\frac{2m\alpha}{L^2},\ \ \ C=\left(\frac{2\beta m}{L^2}+1\right)$$
Completing the square gives
$$\left(\frac{ds}{d\theta}\right)^2=C\left(s+\frac{B}{2A}\right)^2+D, \ \ \ \text{where} \ D=A-\frac{B^2}{4C}$$
A substitution of $s+\frac{B}{2A}=u$ gives
$$\left(\frac{du}{d\theta}\right)^2=Cu^2+D$$
Now the integral is
$$\theta-\theta_0=\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{Cu^2+D}}$$
This is computed via a substitution of $u=\sqrt{\frac{D}{C}}v$
$$\theta-\theta_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{C}}\int\frac{dv}{\sqrt{v^2+1}}$$
Which after undoing all substitutions leaves us with:
$$\theta-\theta_0= \frac{1}{\sqrt{C}}\ln\left|\sqrt{\frac{C}{D}}(s+\frac{B}{2A})+\sqrt{\frac{C}{D}(s+\frac{B}{2A})^2+1}\right|$$
Where the constants $A,B,C,D$ are given by
$$A=-\frac{2mE}{L^2},\ \ \ B=\frac{2m\alpha}{L^2},\ \ \ C=\left(\frac{2\beta m}{L^2}+1\right),\ \ \ D=A-\frac{B^2}{4C}$$
Needless to say, this to me does not look like the correct equation for the trajectory of a particle in a central field. If anyone could advise further on the matter It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Once you have the equation for $du/d\theta$, notice that the solutions are $u(\theta)=\sqrt{D/C}\sinh(\theta \sqrt{C})$, or $\cosh$ or $\sin$ or $\cos$ replacing the $\sinh$, depending on the sign of various constants. These are indeed orbital trajectories!

Comment: $\ln(x + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}) = \sinh^{-1}(x) = -i \sin^{-1}(ix)$

Comment: Ah! So converting to this form will more easily allow me to solve for trajectories. With regards to integrations of this form would you recommend similar techniques? For example, the effective potential of a particle of mass $m$ moving in the vicinity of a black hole is $$U_{eff}(r)=-\frac{GMm}{r}+\frac{L^2}{2\mu r^2}-\frac{GML^2}{c^2\mu r^3}$$. This is also of the form $u=\frac{1}{r}$ and after some approximations resembles the effective potential above. I am assuming the Binet equation would do better in this case, as the integral is undoubtedly more difficult.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert

Comment: The Binet equation for the Schwarzschild "potential" ends up being non-linear, and doesn't have a nice solution.  It might be possible to write down a formal solution, but I think you'd end up needing to solve that same integral or one like it.